# Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime): Clear cookies with Facebook and WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, cookies, windows-phone-8.1

I work on a Facebook login app on Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime), using WebAuthenticationBroker and the example seen at [Windows Phone 8.1 WebAuthenticationBroker Implementation](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Authentication_Using_Facebook,_Google_and_Microsoft_Account_in_Universal_Apps_Using_MVVM).

It works well, I just want that, each time the user want to authorize an app, his previous logon entered values are empty, EVEN IF he checked earlier that he consented to allow the browser to remember his ids.

[image: facebook login]

I tried many ways, especially clearing cookies in that way:

```
Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter(); 
var cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager; 
HttpCookieCollection myCookieJar = cookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri("uri")); 
foreach (HttpCookie cookie in myCookieJar) 
{ 
  cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie); 
}
```

Putting the same uri of authentication in the "uri" string, but the var myCookieJar is empty.

Also, I'm not sure we can access the cookies of the WebView, so, is there an other way to clear thoses datas ?

Thanks,

Gwen

Comment: Using the CookieManager you can indeed access to WebView control. But not WebAuthenticationBroker.

Comment: @kiewic Yes but, as I said earlier, it doesn't clear the cookies. Any way to clear cookies for a specific url ?

Comment: Do you have any example? What is the `Set-Cookie` header you are receiving in the response, and what is the `Cookie` header you are sending in the following request?